# Mqtt sample app is not keeping connection on android 5.1.1

Tags: android, mqtt

I am trying to use MQTT in my app for real-time notifications.
As a client library I'm using Eclipse Paho.
Here is their sample android application:
https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/android/

On `Android 4` it works fine - if I'm connected and my device goes into sleep mode, mqttClient is sending periodic pings and keeps connection alive.
But on my `Android 5.1.1` connection is being torn after a short period when device goes to sleep mode.

The strange thing is that I still have wifi connection, wifi is not disconnected (I have implemented a BroadcastReceiver for this), but for some reason MQTT-connection is not persisted.

I have tested the sample app by Eclipse, implemented my own service with wakelocks and periodic pings - same story.

Does anyone know why is this happening? Any workaround for this?

for reference: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=482442

update: found out that if I set keepAlive timeout to 10 seconds, connection is persisted. If it's 20 seconds, then connection is dropped. Same scenario happens when using http://socket.io (10 seconds pings - connection is persisted, 20 seconds pings - connection is dropped).
Does anyone know why?

Comment: There's no such thing as `Android 4`, which exactly version of Android it worked on? I'm not very familiar with mqtt but does its implementation on Android requires AlarmManager? If yes then are you aware about this: "Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. (...)"?

Comment: @MarianPaździoch thanks for your reply. by Android 4 I mean minSDK>=14, the device I tested was Android 4.2.2 (Jelly Bean). I know about inexact alarms, and the ping sender uses `setExact()` method on sdk versions >=19.

Comment: Ok, but are you aware about the fact that "Suspiciously short interval will be expanded to 60 seconds"? https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=161244

Comment: @MarianPaździoch I didn't know about that, thank you!
Hm, maybe this is the exact case. When I set next alarm in 10 seconds, device just doesn't go to sleep mode? or what? Have you checked this link posted by me:  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=482442 ?

Comment: Welcome to the google world, where documentation covers only some features :) And please let us know if this is indeed the problem.